# Make border-image overlap main image

Tags: jquery, image-scaling, css

I'm using the CSS3 border-image property to images that will be of various sizes.  I'm using in-line css for the time being.

I want to make it so that the border-image has priority over the main image, so that if the image is slightly bigger than anticipated, the frame appears in front of the image.

Below is my code:

```
<img alt="Thumb_img_0129" src="/thumb_IMG_0129.jpg" 
style='border-width:15px; padding:10px 10px; 
-moz-border-image:url("/images/fancy-frame.jpg") 30 30 stretch; 
-webkit-border-image:url("/images/fancy-frame.jpg") 30 30 stretch; 
-o-border-image:url("/images/fancy-frame.jpg") 30 30 stretch; 
border-image:url("/images/fancy-frame.jpg") 30 30 stretch;' />
```

I know it's a bit clunky being in-line css...but have it this way for the time being...

Thank you!

Comment: I tried z-postiion and post:relative, but neither seem to help.  The main image (Thumb_img) seems to partially overlap the border...and I want the border to have priority.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the border around a wrapping `DIV`. For example:

```
<div style="background-image: url('/thumb_IMG_0129.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
     <div style='border-width:15px; padding:10px 10px; 
          -moz-border-image:url("/images/fancy-frame.jpg") 30 30 stretch; 
          -webkit-border-image:url("/images/fancy-frame.jpg") 30 30 stretch; 
          -o-border-image:url("/images/fancy-frame.jpg") 30 30 stretch; 
          border-image:url("/images/fancy-frame.jpg") 30 30 stretch;'>

          <img src='/thumb_IMG_0129.jpg' style='opacity: 0;'/>

      </div>
</div>
```

Explanation: The first wrapping `DIV` got the image as background. Over that, the secon `DIV` paints the border. Last but not least, the image inside both of them, but invisible, to automatically scale the `DIV`s to the size of the image.

Comment: I'm not totally sure about that. Maybe needs some improvement.

Comment: Unfortunately, when doing this, thumb repeats and seems to appear only partially in the frame.  Is there a way to make background image not repeat and instead stretch to the size of the div?